# Tuple comparison in Python

Tags: python, comparison, tuples

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#notin) :

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of
>   corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element
>   must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and
>   have the same length.
>
> If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first
>   differing elements. For example, cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y]) returns the
>   same as cmp(x,y). If the corresponding element does not exist, the
>   shorter sequence is ordered first (for example, [1,2] < [1,2,3]).

If I understand correctly

```
(a, b, c) < (d, e, f)
```

gives True if

```
a < d and b < e and c < f
```

why

```
(1, 2, 3) < (2, 0, 4)
```

gives True?

how can I do such a comparison?

Comment: The second paragraph you quote explains it: if they are not equal, they are ordered the same as their *first differing element*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is flawed. It's not `and` - it's a cascading comparison.

```
a < d or (a == d and b < e) or (a == d and b == e and c < f)
```

Another way of understanding this for arbitrary length tuples...

```
def tuple_less_than(tuple1, tuple2):
    for item1, item2 in zip(tuple1, tuple2):
        if item1 != item2:
            return item1 < item2
    return len(tuple1) < len(tuple2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply explained, read the values as if they are decimal numbers

`123 < 204`

This is oversimplified, but what I mean, it compare elements one by one, and it ends as soon as the elements are not the same.

Comment: The notion in your example does not work  for cases like `(1, 0, 0) < (2, 3)` though.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like comparing 2 strings.  The first non-equal comparison of each element determines the comparison result.

```
(1, 2, 3) < (2, 3)
True

"123" < "23"
True
```